# File Uploading GUI : Improve

Tags: gui-design

How can I improve the GUI of my file upload form?

[image]

Comment: I'm glad you got an answer to your question, but this question is basically just a 'review my site' type question and isn't helpful or relevant to 99% of future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to upload the file does the user need to click "Choose File" or can they drop and drag in a the file?

Personally I would place the 'Edit' and 'Delete' options further apart from each other to avoid clicking on the wrong link.

And I would change the 'submit' button to 'Upload File', something more meaningful.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Johanne,
They really need to click the choose file. I dont know any way to make the edit and delete options.